# Associativity of concatenation of path homotopies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Suppose that X is a topological space. Suppose that $f,g,h: I\to X$ are given paths such that their concatenation is defined. Then I want to prove that $([f][g])([h])=[f]([g][h]),$ where [.] denotes the path homotopy class of .

I drew an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Y36L.jpg) and using that I arrived at $F:I\times I\to X$, which I expected to be continuous. $F$ is as follows:

$F(s,t)=\begin{cases}f\left(\frac s{t+1}\right); t\ge 4s-1\\
g\left(s-\frac t4 \right); 4s-2\le t\le 4s-1\\
h\left (-\frac st+\left (1+\frac 1t\right)\right); t\le 4s-2\end{cases}$

But as it can be seen from the above, $F(s,0)$ blows up when $s>\frac 12$. Can anyone please explain what went wrong in my calculation and suggest how to fix it? Thanks.

From the linked image:

$s\mapsto \frac s{t+1}$ is the map that takes $0\mapsto 0, \frac{t+1}4\mapsto \frac 14$.

$s\mapsto s-\frac t4$ is the map that takes $\frac{t+1}4\mapsto \frac 14, \frac{t+2}4\mapsto\frac 12.$

$s\mapsto -\frac st+1+\frac 1t$ is the map that takes $\frac{t+2}4\mapsto\frac 12, 1\mapsto 1$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A doubt in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878590/a-doubt-in-hatchers-algebraic-topology)

Comment: @AnneBauval: Thanks for the link. It indeed provides a proof of associativity but what I want to know is what went wrong in my working as I'm new to this and I'm trying to learn how to write  homotopies using the pictures. Some of my last few questions are of the same spirit.

Comment: I know but I cannot guess how the picture led you to such a (wrong) $F.$

Comment: @AnneBauval: I tried to elaborate it on the last part of the post. So I considered the horizontal line in the square and where it intersects the tilted lines, then I found a linear function by sending the points of intersections to the lowest horizontal side of the square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your linked image, I would rather take (given $t\in[0,1]$):

- $f$ applied to the affine function of $s$ which goes from $0$ to $1$ when $s$ varies from $0$ to $\frac{1+t}4,$ followed by
- $g$ applied to the affine function of $s$ which goes from $0$ to $1$ when $s$ varies from $\frac{1+t}4$ to $\frac{2+t}4,$ followed by
- $h$ applied to the affine function of $s$ which goes from $0$ to $1$ when $s$ varies from $\frac{2+t}4$ to $1,$ i.e.
  $$F(s,t)=\begin{cases}f\left(\frac{4s}{1+t}\right)&\text{if }4s\le1+t\\
  g\left(4s-t-1\right)&\text{if }1+t\le4s\le2+t\\
  h\left (\frac{4s-2-t}{2-t}\right)&\text{if }4s\ge2+t.\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm starting to understand homotopies now. So the idea is: for every segment [_,_], we want to squeeze in all of the path. That's why, as s varies from 0 to (1+t)/4, you take the affine function as you did. :-)